# Model for obtaining the magnetic moment of a neutron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

The anomalous magnetic moment of a neutron ($g_s=-3.83$) could be considered as a fixed proton ($g_s=5.58$) with an orbiting $\pi⁻$ meson in an $l=1$ state.

a) What is the magnetic dipole moment of such a configuration?

b) Is it possible to account for the account for the observed neutron magnetic moment from such a model? Suppose that the wavefunction for the neutron has two parts: one corresponding to $g_s=0$ and the other due to the proton plus the pion. What would be the relative sizes of the two pieces of the wavefunction?

**Part a**

I've assumed that the magnetic moment is the addition of the spin magnetic moment of the proton (since it's fixed and there's no orbital contribution) and the orbital moment for the pion (since its spin is 0 and there's no spin contribution to the magnetic moment)

$$ \mu_s= g_s  s \mu_N=5.58\times 1/2 \mu_N  $$
$$ \mu_l=\frac{q\hbar l}{2m}=\frac{-e \hbar}{2m_{\pi⁻}}=-e\frac{m_p}{m_{\pi⁻}}\mu_N$$
$$\mu_{tot}=\mu_s+\mu_l$$

I think this part is correct but I'm not very sure. My question is: is it possible to add two different contributions to the magnetic moment like this?

**Part b**

This is the problematic part. I express the wavefunction as

$$ \left|{\psi}\right>=A\left|{n}\right>+B\left|{p\pi⁻}\right>$$

I assume the normalization condition which gives

$$\left|{A}\right|²+\left|B\right|²=1$$

The magnetic moment would be something like this

$$\mu = \mu_n \left|{A}\right|² + \mu_{tot}\left|B\right|² $$

but I don't know how to substitute $\mu_n$, because, if $g_s=0$ then it looks like there wasn't any magnetic moment from this part.

Can anyone give me some guidance in this part? How can I express the theoretical magnetic moment of a neutron taking into account that $g_s=0$ ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: its better to see 'quark model' for an explanation of neutron's magnetic moment!

Comment: I think that the request for guidance on part b is on-topic, and the question should remain open.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311101/226902